# Length of calloc array of characters using the null char value?

Tags: c, arrays, count, null, calloc

I have a 2d array of pointers to calloc'ed arrays of chars. Assuming that calloc 0's out a character array, is it possible to count how many characters there are in the array similar to:

```
while( next character != '\0' ){
    count++;
} return count;
```

?

To be more specific:

```
letters[j] = calloc(26, sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", letters[j]);
```

here is the code where I calloc the char array, then set it to a specific string no longer than 26 characters, but can be less.

Comment: So you have a `char *[ROWS][COLS]`? Provide a [mcve] and state your **specific** problem. We are not a "do my homework" service.

Comment: If they were `calloc`ed and not filled in, you'll count nothing. You can't determine the size of the allocation this way, just the length of a `NUL` terminated string. Why you'd write this code in any event is beyond me though; `strlen` exists, use it.

Comment: Easy: `int count = 0; while( letters[j][count] != '\0' ){ count++; } return count;`

Answer (score -1):

```
int lengthOfString(char* string){
    int count = 0;
    while(string[count] != '\0'){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Yes, This works perfectly!

Comment: Again, why not just use `strlen`?